# how to pass a parameter in below code?? can anyone tell me how?

Tags: android

I want to give a parameter in Search function (in Text field) **id** by taking that id it should retrieve a single record and display that id details. Instead of giving select * from emp where id=12345;

Output:

Enter id: *12345*

*Displays data in a row view*

UserActivity.java

```
public class UserActivity extends Activity {

SQLiteDatabase db;
TableRow tableRow;
TextView textview,textview1,textview2,textview3,textview4,textview5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("EMP",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
}



public void Search(View view)
{   
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM EMP where id=225618",null);
int count=c.getCount();
c.moveToFirst();
TableLayout tableLayout= new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
tableLayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
TableRow tableRow;
TextView textview,textview1,textview2,textview3,textview4,textview5;
tableRow=new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
textview=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
textview.setText("Empid");
textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);
textview.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
textview.setPadding(10, 8, 3, 5);
tableRow.addView(textview);
textview4=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
textview4.setText("Ename");
textview4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
textview4.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
textview4.setPadding(35, 8, 3, 5);
tableRow.addView(textview4);
textview5=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
textview5.setText("Email");
textview5.setTextColor(Color.RED);
textview5.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
textview5.setPadding(60, 8, 3, 5);
tableRow.addView(textview5);
tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
for (Integer j=0; j< count; j++)
{
tableRow= new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
textview1=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
textview1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
textview2=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
textview2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
textview3=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
textview3.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("email")));
textview1.setPadding(10, 5, 3, 5);
textview2.setPadding(35, 5, 3, 5);
textview3.setPadding(60, 5, 3, 5);
tableRow.addView(textview1);
tableRow.addView(textview2);
tableRow.addView(textview3);
tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
c.moveToNext();
}
setContentView(tableLayout);
db.close();
}
```

Comment: from where are you calling Search() function?

Comment: in useractivity i have placed a text field and under that search button will be there

Comment: then on that button click, you can call Search(view, id), is this you want?

Comment: yes, but how id value will have the empId in run time?

Comment: what is the purpose of textfield, is not giving you the empid ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters with views using [setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 0):

In search() method. First get the edittext field data.Then mention that in a Query:

something like:

```
public void Search(View view)
{  
  EditText edittext=(EditText) findViewById(edit field id);
  String textfiled_id=edittext.getText().toString();
  Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM EMP where id='"+textfiled_id+"'",null);
  ............
  ........... your code
}
```

Comment: thank you very much user543 it is working perfect i could see expected result my project is completed woth your help thaku very much :)